# WooCommerce get default shipping rate & conditions

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

WooCommerce has by default several shipping methods among which:

- flat rate,
- free shipping.

The latter can be triggered based on a condition (minimum order for instance).

As the base rate and the minimum order price required to get free shipping are displayed in several places in the theme I'm developing, I would like to know if there's a way to get them programmatically rather than hardcoding these values.